# Problems with converting html table to PDF using ITextRenderer

Tags: java, html, pdf-generation

Our customer has a template in html, which he wants to be filled with data and converted to PDF. Everything works fine, the problem is only with templates, which have two columns. The template is interpreted as html `<table>` with two cells, each containing a large amount of text (about 2 pages, it's a bilingual contract, one column is Czech, other is English). I can't stop the customer from creating templates in this really stupid way.

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td style="vertical-align: top;">
              long long text inside one <div></div> tag
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">
              long long text inside one <div></div> tag
            </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>

some other div
```

When this template is converted to PDF, there are large white spaces in the columns in the middle of sentences, even though the content could fit in one page.

[image]

Html content is is fine, the problem will be somewhere in rendering.
We take the String with html content

```
String content = html content;
byte[] bytes = content.getBytes("UTF-8);
InputStream htmlIs = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setInputEncoding("UTF-8");
tidy.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");
tidy.setXHTML(true);
Document xhtmlDoc = tidy.parseDOM(htmlIs, null);

// to pdf
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
... get fonts
renderer.setDocument(xhtmlDoc, null);
try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(baos);
    return baos;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see any large white spaces in the middle of sentences.

Comment: well in a picture on the first page text is cut off in the middle of the sentence and continues on the second page - entire second page could fit in with the first one

Comment: Ah, you meant the unexpected page break, sorry. I hadn't realised.